# How to change to Admin mode in CMD?

Tags: windows-10

When we open the CMD in normal way it will open with normal privileges. Is there any way we can change the mode by giving a command? (like sudo in Linux)

Thanks in advance.

PS: ctrl + shift + enter is not what I am asking

Answer (score 1):

Not natively. There is software that behaves like sudo in linux that pulls off some trickery to get this done, but it still opens a second cmd window. I gave it a go in the past, but it feels insecure, so I stopped using it.

Nircmd has an option to run a command as elevated which is probably the best option, but still..

Its much easier to start the command prompt as admin directly. True, there is one occassion where it would be awesome to do this, but that happens so infrequently, its just not worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If a method can open a new cmd but in the path of current window that should be great as well. any way?

Comment: @PHPst see here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/05cce5f6-3c3a-4bb8-8b72-8c1ce4b5eff1/how-to-run-a-program-as-adminitrator-via-the-command-line?forum=w7itproappcompat

Answer (score 0):

You can pass admin privilege to a batch file if you want to execute it. a UAC window will pop-up to ask you for the privilege.

You may check this: https://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html

I also copying the following code from a batch file that asks for a privilege. You may find it useful. I am not big expert in this and I am only copying it for your own reference. I don't know every single word of it. But it obviously saves some line codes in a file of .vbs extension then calls it.

```
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" 
"%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > 
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B
```

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"